# I want to calculate Week-Ending date for particular dates given in a separate column

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I am currently working on SQL Server 2019. There is need to calculate week-ending date (every Sunday) for a given effective date in a column. I am trying to make it work using the below logic.

```
dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530107',GETDATE()+13)/7)*7)+7,'17530107') as Weekend_Date
```

Desired Output,

- Effective Date ( this date is give):   Week-Ending Date (this needs to be calculated)(desired output)
  10/08/2019                                       **10/13/2019**
  11/01/2019                                       **11/03/2019**
  11/07/2019                                       **11/10/2019**

Answer (score 0):

If Getdate() is the field from your database and Sunday is day of week 1 then this should work.

`Select dateadd (dd,(7- datepart(dw,getdate()) + 1),cast(getdate() as date))`

Comment: Yes, Getdate () is the field from the database but Sunday does not necessarily have to be the day of week 1. It can be the Sunday of any week depending on the given date. For example, if the given date is 12/02/2019 the Sunday should be on 12/08/2019, given date is 12/12/2019, the Sunday should be on 12/15/2019 and son on.  the above code runs successfully but does not return anything.

Comment: If you run datepart(dw,getdate()) what do you get?

Comment: Running "Select dateadd (dd,(7- datepart(dw,getdate()) + 1),cast(getdate() as date))" gets me current date.

Comment: If you run select datepart(dw,getdate()) what do you get?

Comment: select datepart(dw,getdate()) returns an integer

Comment: Yes, it is the day of the week. What is the number?

Comment: Yes, It returns integer 5 as the day of the week.

Comment: Then Saturday is day 7 so the above code should return the next Sunday for any date you use to replace getdate(). 7 - 5+1 = 3 so if you add three days to the date you get Sunday.

Comment: Should be (7-5) + 1 = 3